# When my page is loading my popup opens many times

Tags: popup

I want "#my_popup" to show on page load, if ".one" contains a text. The problem is now that "#my_popup" is open many many times. I don't know why,it should only open once.

```
 $(function(){ 
        $('.one:contains("any text")').closest('#my_popup').popup('show');
        return false; 
        });
```

I hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have multiple DOM elements with class `.one` within your page. Each one would open the popup. If you simply want to use the first element you might use the jQuery method `first()` to get rid of any further results. So simpy change your code to:

```
$(function(){ 
    $('.one:contains("any text")').first().closest('#my_popup').popup('show');
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer! Yes your are right, this is the problem. The case is that I want to check, if one of the ".one"-elements contains the text "any text", no matter which one, then open the popup. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @fala Glad that I could help =) You may consider to upvote and/or mark the answer with a check if it helped you to solve your problem. This helpes future readers to get their answers faster.

Answer (score 0):

may be "one" is a class. try to make it "ID".